# trace stack external library eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, stack, mpi

I imported mpi.jar library in Eclipse and everything works perfectly. I would like to trace the stack of my application but I don't know I to do it. For example, my app calls a method from mpi.jar library called send() and I would like to understand what send() does. I know that Send() method calls other methods and I would like to trace all these calls internal to Send(). 
Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Do you have source code for your imported jar?

Comment: @moffeltje I know how to debug code without an external library but I don't know how to trace external calls of an imported jar

Comment: @NickJ Yes I have the source code. I tried to open it and read it but I cannot follow all the calls, because of this I would like to do it with eclipse.

Comment: When debugging code in eclipse, it makes no difference whether it's your code or code in an imported jar. Just put a break-point where your code calls send(), and click 'step into'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set an Eclipse breakpoint and launch the application in Debug mode. Then the IDE will be stopping at the breakpoint and you can step into mpi.jar library.
If the source is not directly found you have to navigate and point Eclipse to it.
Then you should be able to continue to debug the mpi.jar library.

Comment: Class File Editor should open when you enter a method from the library. In the class file editor is an attach source button which can be used to attach either source code from workspace or from an external zip file.